# Assign object of proprieties to an other exiting object with the same proprieties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to assign the first object to the second object that have the same properties. What you suggest as quick method? Do I need to loop over the stores object separately?

1st object:

```
{
  title: 'test',
  description: 'desc',
  tags: ['tag1','tag2']
}
```

2nd object:

```
{
 title: '',
 description: '',
 tags: [],
 stores: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        tags: '',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        tags: '',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: false
    }
 ]
}
```

Results:

```
{
 title: 'test',
 description: 'desc',
 tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
 stores: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'test',
        description: 'desc',
        tags: '['tag1', 'tag2']',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'test',
        description: 'desc',
        tags: '['tag1', 'tag2']',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: false
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Use `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Yes, you need to loop over the `stores` array separately. There's nothing that automatically recurses this.

Comment: yah that what I thought

Comment: I don't know if there is a function in Lodash or another library that can handle that

Comment: You can use recursion, the only issue is the `tags` key that has a value typeof 'object' but we don't want to traverse it. Thus, I've added a check for that particular key in my answer below. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use object spread operator to shallow merge.

Try this.

```js
let obj1 = {
    title: 'test',
    description: 'desc',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
};

let obj2 = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    tags: [],
    stores: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: '',
            description: '',
            tags: '',
            template: '',
            link: '',
            active: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: '',
            description: '',
            tags: '',
            template: '',
            link: '',
            active: false
        }
    ]
};

console.log({...obj2, ...obj1});
```

If you want to merge the deeply nested object then you could use the below approach.

```js
let obj1 = {
    title: 'test',
    description: 'desc',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
};

let obj2 = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    tags: [],
    stores: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: '',
            description: '',
            tags: '',
            template: '',
            link: '',
            active: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: '',
            description: '',
            tags: '',
            template: '',
            link: '',
            active: false
        }
    ]
};

function isObject(item) {
    return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

function deepMerge(target, ...sources) {
    if (!sources.length) return target;
    const source = sources.shift();
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
        for (const key in source) {
            if (isObject(source[key])) {
                if (!target[key]) Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
                mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
            } else {
                Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
            }
        }
    }
    return deepMerge(target, ...sources);
}

console.log(deepMerge(obj2, obj1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want some kind of recursive function to go through all the keys and check if they exist on the other object, something like:

```js
let a = {
  title: "test",
  description: "desc",
  tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
};

let b = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  tags: [],
  stores: [{
      id: 1,
      title: "",
      description: "",
      tags: "",
      template: "",
      link: "",
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "",
      description: "",
      tags: "",
      template: "",
      link: "",
      active: false,
    },
  ],
};

const merge = (a, b) => {
  Object.keys(b).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof b[key] === "object" && key !== 'tags') {
      merge(a, b[key]);
    }

    if (Object.keys(a).includes(key)) {
      b[key] = a[key];
    }
  });
};

merge(a, b);

console.log(b);

console.log(b.stores[0].tags); // [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]
```

I had to add a check for the case of the key `tags` which even though is an object, we don't want to go deeper into it. Nonetheless, this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I already done a similar function but thank you for the direction.

Comment: Good stuff, my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  title: 'test',
  description: 'desc',
  tags: ['tag1','tag2']
};

let obj2 = {
 title: '',
 description: '',
 tags: [],
 stores: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        tags: '',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        tags: '',
        template: '',
        link: '',
        active: false
    }
 ]
}

console.log(Object.assign(obj2, obj))
```

Just using `Object.assign`, and flip between two object as parameter will do

Comment: This only assigns to the top-level object, not the `stores` array.